# How do I apply pymc categorical to a large set of different probabilities

Tags: pymc

I have a problem involving many objects, N which can each be in a fixed number of states, j.
We know the probability of an object being in each of the states - but the probabilities vary between objects.

For example, if there are j=3 states and N=2 objects the probabilities could be described as:

```py
P_object1 = [0.1,0.8,0.1]
P_object2 = [0.05,0.05,0.99]
```

For a low number of objects I can just write:

```py
state_object1 = mc.Categorical("StateObject1", P_object1, size=1)
state_object2 = mc.Categorical("StateObject2", P_object2, size=1)
```

However, I have a large number of objects...

What I want to create is a vector of integers corresponding to the random states where each row corresponds to an individual object.

I have tried to implement a collection to do this:

```py
objectIDs = np.empty(nGrains, dtype=object)
objectIDs_0 = mc.Categorical('objectID_0', probs[0])
objectIDs[0] = objectIDs_0
for i in range(1, N):    
    objectIDs[i] = mc.Categorical('objectID_%i' %i, probs[i])
```

The problem comes when I try to use this in the next step:

```py
@mc.deterministic
def lambda_S(nI=nI, objectIDs=objectIDs, closureAges=closureAges):
    out = np.empty(N)
    for i in range(N):    
        out[i] = nI[i] * ( math.exp( lambda_U238*stateValue[objectIDs[i]]*1.E6 ) - 1 ) / b
    return out
```

In the above nI is a vector of integers and the stateValue is a vector of doubles, one for each state. The problem is that this returns an array of doubles rather than a pymc object so that it fails when I try to run the model...

Answer (score 0):

If your categorical probabilities are fixed and known, what are you trying to estimate? I don't see any observed nodes that represent a likelihood.